# basic php file upload system

Tags: php, html, webserver

im building a file upload/dwnload app in php..im using the following form

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Upload Index</title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype=“multipart/form-data” action=“files.php” method=“post”>
    <p>Choose your file to upload!
  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
          <br />
      And what would you like to call it? <input name=“title” type=“text” />
    </p>
    <p><br />
    </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

instead of going to the "files.php" it directs itself to some weird URL...something    like this:
    http://project360.in/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%93files.php%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D?    uploadedfile=buglog.txt&%E2%80%9Ctitle%E2%80%9D=
    any idea what should be done to fix this?

Comment: do you use wordpad for editing? i see you have the `“` character instead of `"` to enclose some attributes (ie. in the `<form>` tag and the last `<input>` field). --edit: yup that's it, your browser is url-encoding them... see also @AVD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove smart-quote `“ ”`.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="files.php" method="post">
    <p>Choose your file to upload!
  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
          <br />
      And what would you like to call it? <input name="title" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p><br />
    </p>
</form>
```