# href not showing up on the web page

Tags: html

For some reason my href link is not showing up on the page. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> MY FIRST WEB PAGE </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> This is my first Web Page </h1> 
    <h2> What this is</h2>
    <p> <strong>RUSH </strong> is my <em>favorite</em> rock group </p>
    <h2> Why this is</h2>
    <p> To learn HTML </p> 
    <ul> 
        <li> To learn HTML</li>
        <li></li>
        <li> To show off </li>
        <ol>
        <li> To my boss </li>
        <li> To my friends </li>
        <li> To my cat </li>
        </ol>
    <li> Because I have fallen in love with my computer
         and I want to give her some HTML loving </li>
    </ul>

    <h2> where to find tutorial</h2>
    <p><a href="http://www.htmldog.com”> HTML Dog </a></p>  

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I'm using OSX 10.11

Comment: Replace `”` by `"`. You’re likely using TextEdit. Uncheck the option “smart quotes” in the options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [basic php file upload system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310245/basic-php-file-upload-system)

Comment: If you have an HTML question, it's probably (always) a good idea to run it through the "official" HTML checker: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input When that reports zero errors or warnings, usually your error will disappear. In this case note that it says `End of file reached when inside an attribute value. Ignoring tag.` This gives you a hint that an attribute on a tag was not closed properly, and as others have said, the culprit is your "smart quote".

Comment: thanks. I undid all of that an now I see "HTML DOG". When I click on it, i get page not found. I thought I was supposed to see the whole link. No?

Answer (score 3):

You have a closing smart-quote not a standard double quote in the href

Answer (score 0):

In case someone does not know what smart-quotes are:

```
<p><a href="http://www.htmldog.com”> HTML Dog </a></p>
```

to

```
<p><a href="http://www.htmldog.com"> HTML Dog </a></p>
```

And the explanation - the quotes around your href are wrong (to be specific - the last quote is wrong) - as mentioned in the other answers, you can turn them off by following [this guide](http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks).

I would recommend to use a specific editor which supports you with these kind of problems .. try "[sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)" or "[brackets](http://brackets.io/)"

Comment: thanks. I got it to work. I was expecting to see the http link but "HTML DOG"  is displaying. Is that how href works?

Comment: yes. that is how it works. If you want the full link to be displayed you need to simply put the full adress between the <a> tags, like `<p><a href="http://www.htmldog.com"> http://www.htmldog.com </a></p>`